# How to get accentColor background for menu items in SwiftUI with reduced transparency?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Using AppKit you can add `NSMenuItem`s to an `NSMenu`. I saw that there is something similar to NSMenu in SwiftUI, namely [`MenuButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubutton). But I cannot find any documentation on how it works.

I tried the following:

```
MenuButton("+") {
    Button("New contact") { print("Create new contact") }
    Button("New group") { print("Create new group") }
}
```

And that gives me this

[image: an opened MenuButton]

It looks almost OK **but** when I enable the "Reduce transparency" in system preferences

- The buttons have a different background color than the menu (notice the slightly lighter color above and beneath the menu items).
- When I hover the menu items, their background color doesn't change like a normal macOS menu. See the image below:

[image: Highlighted menu item]

I also tried to change the background color manually using the `.background()` modifier but that doesn't affect the full width of the menu item.

```
MenuButton("+") {
    Button("New contact") { print("Create new contact") }
        .background(Color.accentColor)
    Button("New group") { print("Create new group") }
}
```

[image: Menu with manually changed background]

I suppose this is because I am placing `Button`s inside the `MenuButton` while it is probably expecting some other SwiftUI element. What elements should I place inside MenuButtons to create a normal looking macOS menu like the one below?

[image: Correctly rendered MenuButton on Catalina]

## [Update] macOS Big Sur

I also tried this out in Big Sur. While the background renders correctly, in Big Sur, the text color is messed up now.

[image: Incorrectly highlighted menu on Big Sur]

Comment: did you try .background() out of MenuButton("+") instead Button?

Comment: I tried MenuButton("+") { Button("Hello") {doNothing()}.background(.blue) }. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: this: (sorry I can't test now by myself) --> MenuButton("+") { Button("Hello") {doNothing()}}.background(.blue)

Comment: @SimonePistecchia that gives me a blue background behind the + button and not behind the hovered menu item.

Comment: All works fine here. Tested with Xcode 11.2.1 / macOS 10.15.2. I even tried with changed `menuButtonStyle`. What else have you changed except accent color?

Comment: I am on Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504) / macOS 10.15.2 (19C57) haven't tried with Xcode 11.2.1 though. I don't think I changed anything except the accent color.

Comment: I tried with Xcode 11.3.1 and macOS 10.15.2. It works for me.

Comment: OK, thanks @Asperi and iSpain17. I tried the same build that behaved strangely on my computer, on another computer and indeed, it works like normal on the other computer... I'm still wondering what's happening on my computer though. I restarted and all but it still stays the same...

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux Do you have, by any chance, the „Reduce transparency“ option on (System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce transparency)? I just run into this rendering issue using standard AppKit APIs myself, and then stumbled upon your question here. After disabling this option, the rendering works just fine for me. Can you confirm?

Comment: @lukas-kubanek Yes "Reduce transparency" was the culprit. Thanks a lot! You made my day 

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux: Thanks for the confirmation. I tested it on macOS 11 Big Sur, and it seems to work there again. Nevertheless, I filed a feedback for the issue on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina. Feel free to duplicate my version here: https://github.com/structuredpath/AppleBugReports/tree/master/FB7858713

Comment: How did you get it to work on Big Sur? When I reduce transparency I still get a bad appearance. I added a screenshot in an update of my question. Did our get to work using AppKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux Good catch on `Reduce Transparency`. I personally always have it turned on, so this is a big problem for me. Have you a workaround? I suppose the good folk at Apple always have it turned off, so noone seems to have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a partial solution to this by configuring a `ButtonStyle` and applying it to the `MenuButton` generic structure. Note however that the conditional change of `.foregroundColor` isn't inherited by the individual's `Button()`'s `Text()`. Also the color ain't right.

Perhaps someone wants to improve on this.

```swift
struct DetectHover: ButtonStyle {
    @State private var hovering: Bool = false

    public func makeBody(configuration: DetectHover.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(self.hovering ? Color.white : Color.primary)
            .background(self.hovering ? Color.blue : Color.clear)
            .onHover { hover in
                self.hovering = hover
            }
    }
}
```

```swift
MenuButton(label: Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.actionTemplateName)!)) {

// Buttons

}.buttonStyle(DetectHover())
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got something that *nearly* looks right. I have created a custom button which does change appearance when hovered.

I am very new to both Swift and SwiftUI, so the following may be clumsy. I would welcome any improvements.

```swift
struct HoverButton: View {
    var text = "Hover Button"
    var action = {}
    @State private var hovering = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(text, action: action )
            .padding(.horizontal, 6)
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(self.hovering ? Color(.selectedMenuItemColor) : Color(.clear))
            .onHover { hover in
                self.hovering = hover
            }
    }
}

//  Usage:
MenuButton("Test") {
    HoverButton(text: "Apple", action:  {
        print("Apple")
    })
    HoverButton(text: "Banana", action:  {
        print("Banana")
    })
}
.font(.system(size: 14, /* weight: .heavy, */ design: .default))
.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
```

The whole point in creating the custom button is to have access to `Self` so that I can change its appearance. However, there are some serious shortcomings:

- The main problem is that the buttons don’t take the full width of the menu body. I have no idea how to fix that.
- The menu buttons are centered. I tried using a `HStack` with a `Spacer()` but that didn’t help.
- I have no idea how to omit the first parameter name as for a real `Button`